# Heroku Nodejs Deployment error: App crashed

Tags: node.js, heroku-toolbelt

[image: Log image]
This is my Heroku log when I deploy my app the build is successful but the app crashes with code 503

```
2015-07-04T12:17:49.485610+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mycityweather.herokuapp.com request_id=37e7fe0c-63fe-4f96-8d17-857df8cfc0c2 fwd="150.129.28.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2015-07-04T12:17:50.040740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mycityweather.herok  uapp.com request_id=fc18d77b-8ff5-4a7a-ae4c-5be89d17365b fwd="150.129.28.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What is the reason for that error? And what is the solution for it?

This is my main app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cluster =require("cluster");
var cpusNum=require('os').cpus().length;
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();
var port=process.env.PORT || 3000;
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);




// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
if(cluster.isMaster)
{
  //fork Workers
  for(var i=0;i<cpusNum;i++)
  {
    cluster.fork();
  }
    cluster.on('exit',function(worker,code,signal){
    console.log("Worker with "+ worker.process.pid + 'died');
  });
}
else{
    app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
    });
}
module.exports = app;
```

This is my main entry point file and there is no proper error message that will show me exact cause for iy.

Comment: how are you configuring your server? can you share your server code?

Answer (score 1):

Got it there was error in npm versions on server side and my local machine.